# Invalid IL Code Unity System.Data reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5

I have the .NET Framework Unity v3.5 System.Data reference assembly in the assets folder of Unity. When calling `DataTable.Rows[x]` I get this error:

> InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Data.DataTable:get_Rows (): IL_0000: ret
>
> Sorcerer..ctor (System.Data.DataTable dt, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 LoadDeck, UnityEngine.GameObject cardPref, System.String Prefix) (at Assets/Sorcerer.cs:43)
>   Game.Start () (at Assets/Game.cs:37)"

When calling `DataTable.Select(query)`, I get:

> InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Data.DataTable:Select (string): IL_0000: ret
>
> Sorcerer..ctor (System.Data.DataTable dt, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 LoadDeck, UnityEngine.GameObject cardPref, System.String Prefix) (at Assets/Sorcerer.cs:42)
>   Game.Start () (at Assets/Game.cs:37)"
>
> The System.Data.dll I'm using is from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Unity Full v3.5"

Comment: Why? You've obviously researched the question (but have not shown results of your research which may cause downvotes on the post) and found articles like http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/517264/unity-and-the-dlls.html... So it is not clear why you trying to use one from full .Net framework.

Comment: That's not the issue, I'm using the .NET Framework designed for Unity and placing it in the Assets Folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem when i use dll from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Unity Full v3.5". I solved it by using the dll from "Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0". 
Hope it helps.